# Displaying the Verilog parameter name

Tags: parameters, verilog, system-verilog

I am using the `parameter` keyword to define a state, i.e., `RESET` = 5'b00000.  If I want to use `$display` to print out the state name instead of the binary representation, or display the state name in my simulation wave viewer, how can I do this?  It doesn't work to try to print it out as a string (as you would expect), so I'm wondering if this can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know of a way to automatically `$display` the name of a `parameter`.  However, if you don't mind duplicating your code, you could create a `task` (or `function`) to accomplish your goal:

```
    task show_name_state;
        case (state)
            5'b00000: $display("RESET");
            5'b00001: $display("WAIT");
        endcase
    endtask

    $display(state); show_name_state();
```

I know of at least one (expensive) Verilog debugger which has the capability to recognize parameters and automatically display their names in its waveform viewer: the Verdi (formerly Debussy) nWave tool can do this.

Comment: You can of course replace the 5'b00000 in the case statement with the parameter RESET instead.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is just the display the name of the state during simulation, I will usually do something like

```
`ifdef SIMULATION
reg [127:0] __state__;
case (state)
  STATE_1 : __state__ = "STATE_1";
  STATE_2 : __state__ = "STATE_2";
  default : __state__ = "error";
endcase
`endif
```

Where state is the state register that has the parameter in question.

Answer (score 1):

There can be several parameters with the same value, so you cannot in general go from a numeric value to the name of a parameter with that value.  Parameters are like C `#define`s; although you can use them to define a set of states, there is no formal association between the variable and the list of parameters you are using to represent the possible states.  Because there was no better option it used to be common to (mis)use parameters in this way, but then SystemVerilog introduced an `enum` type which does not have the issues of the parameter method.  You did not mention what tools you are using, but assuming that your tools support SystemVerilog enum types then that would be a better choice for a state value.